# Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS installation failed

Tags: 14.04

[image]Yesterday I downloaded `Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS` from the official site(ubuntu.com).Then I made a bootable usb with `startup disk creator`.But when I am trying to install , gives me this error!! why ? and how to solve this issue ? 
I ran this now what ?[image: image of the error]

Comment: Please help me!! I can't install !!

Answer (score 1):

1. Check that the download was OK with md5sum in a terminal window

Code:

md5sum filename.iso

Use the real filename of the downloaded iso file instead of 'filename' in the command. You can find the md5sums to check with at this link

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes

2. Check that it will be possible to write the Ubuntu system to your hard disk drive

If there is not enough empty space on the disk, you need to move / remove some data.

Comment: I have added the result please tell me what to do ?

Comment: I downloaded this image file 2 times, Please don't tell me to download again.. I am using mobile internet 40kb/s

Comment: The checksum is wrong, you will have to download it again until the checksum is 119cb63b48c9a18f31f417f09655efbd
You can try to download it again using ``wget --continue --tries=0 ISO-URL `` (replace ISO-URL with the correct url to the iso) Wget handles slow connections better that your browser